# Extending Lucas's Theorem: $\binom{n}{k} \mod M^2 (M$ is prime$)$

Tags: number-theory, binomial-coefficients

We know that we can calculate $\binom{n}{k} \mod M (M$ is prime$)$, with Lucas's theorem:
$\binom{n}{k} \equiv \binom{n_0}{k_0}.\binom{n_1}{k_1}…\binom{n_{p}}{k_{p}} \ (mod \ M)$

$N=n_0.M^0+n_1.M^1+…+n_{p}.M^{p}$

$K=k_0.M^0+k_1.M^1+…+k_{p}.M^{p}$

But how can we calculate $\binom{n}{k} \mod M^2 (M$ is prime$)$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check out [Andrew Granville's work.](http://www.cecm.sfu.ca/organics/papers/granville/paper/binomial/html/binomial.html)